# Java: Generate N random numbers which mean is going to be M

Tags: java, random

I didn't manage to find such function in Math.random or Util.random. For example I give a mean of 2 and generate N random numbers which when I average them the average to be the number (in this case 2) which I gave to the function.

```
public static int[] randomNumbersWithGivenMean(int average)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: They can't be random then can they? You can have random numbers sampled from a distribution with a mean of `2`, but having the mean of the numbers _be_ `2` defines a definite mathematical relationship between the numbers - think about it this way, I can always define a number `x` which when added to an array of numbers `a` gives a resulting mean `m`.

Comment: What is the mean of the random function you currently have?  Can you leverage that?

Comment: It's easy to do that, if you don't care much about the distribution of the element values. Just create a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of `(average * result.length)`. But creating a random partition with uniform probability is much harder. Could you tell us a bit more about the expected results?

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you generate a list of random numbers in the range of `1..N`, the mean value of the list items will be `N / 2`. The larger your list, the more likely this is to hold true.

```
public static int[] getRandomList(int average, int listSize) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] list = new int[listSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        list[i] = rand.nextInt(average * 2) + 1;
    }

    return list;
}
```

You did not mention the range of numbers you wished to generate, so I have assumed `1..N` will suffice. If you wish to change this you must ensure that you generate the numbers evenly over `average`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for Gaussian distribution random numbers?

Please see [JavaDoc for Class Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

There is a method called `nextGaussian()`, which as stated in the doc:

> Returns the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally") distributed double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

You have to then alter the result to fit your desired standard deviation (by multiplication) and mean (by addition).

The more times you call the `nextGaussian()`, the better (number mean closer to the desired mean) will be.